# Выделить последние элементы, не кратные числу

Tags: css, css3

Как можно с помощью `CSS3`-псевдоселекторов выделить все последние элементы, которые остаются после деления на число `x`?

К примеру, имеется 11 элементов и `x = 3`, тогда первые 9 элементов кратны трем и нужно выделить десятый и одиннадцатый.

Comment: Можно через js сделать

Comment: @Netahaki интересует только css, у самого что-то не выходит

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.add').click(function(){
  $('.container').append('<div class="block">');
})
$('.del').click(function(){
  $('.container .block:last-child').remove();
})
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  counter-reset:counter;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
.block:before{
  counter-increment:counter;
  content:counter(counter);
}

/*
  Алгоритм действий:
  1)выбрать все элементы кратные 3;
  2)Из них выбрать тот, который попадает в позицию три с конца(т.е. последний из кратных);
  3)После него - искомые элементы.
*/
.block:nth-child(3n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3) ~ .block{
  background-color:#cda;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">Добавить блок</button>
<button class="del">Удалить блок</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```